# Rating Control in Windows store apps and Binding integer value to it

Tags: xaml, data-binding, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have the followin

```
g code

<GridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Padding="116,136,116,46"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            Visibility="Collapsed">

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="DarkSeaGreen" BorderThickness="1">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="180" Background="SeaGreen">
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MinHeight="40" FontSize="22"  Margin="15,10,15,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Grid Height="Auto">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>

                             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="TotalMarks:" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TotalMarks}" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Total Questions:" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TotalQuestions}" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Total attempts:" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"  Margin="15,0,0,0" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AttemptCount}" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"   />
                               <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Ratings:" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TestRating}" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                            <!-- Here I want to add -->    

                            </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

        </GridView>
```

I want to add a rating control in the grid in the data template so that its value can be bound with an integer variable`TestRating`. As I am new to databinding I don't how to do this. Please provide some assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends on the `Rating` control you are using. Here's how you would do it with [Callisto's](https://github.com/timheuer/Callisto/wiki/Rating):

```
<callisto:Rating ItemCount="5" Value="{Binding TestRating}" />
```

Assuming the binding works for the `TextBlock` immediately above the spot where you want to insert ratings, this should work as well.

Comment: Hi Damir! thanks for your solution. I tried the same. But one more issue is arising.. It works fine on one page, When I implemented it on another page and setting value like `myCalistocontrol.Value=5`, it does not show any change.

Comment: @JayantVarshney I'd need some more details to help you with that. Are you accesing the control from the first page in this case are just trying to use the control a bit differently? A sample to reproduce the issue would be best. Maybe as a new question since this is a new issue if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate any changes to be reflected in your source, you would need to make the binding two-way for the changes that are made in the control to be bound back to the source. So the appropriate change would be:

```html
<callisto:Rating ItemCount="5" Value="{Binding TestRating, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but dude I asked it on Jan 2013, almost 2 years :)

Comment: I know how long it was, but I was completing the answer as Stackoverflow is a repository that is used as a reference for more than just the person asking the question. I was helping others who might come across the thread.